# retry + circuitbreaker in resilience4j

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, resilience4j

I tried to use retry with only circuitbreaker, even then it is not working. Can you please tell us how to chain them(retry + circuitbreaker) together.
It is giving preference to circuitbreakerm 
`I am using like this :
@CircuitBreaker(name = "backendA", fallbackMethod = "circuitBreakerFallback")
@Retry(name = "backendA", fallbackMethod = "retryFallback")`

I have added this code too in yml file

```
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.circuit-breaker-aspect-order=2
```

resilience4j.retry.retry-aspect-order=1

Still doesent work ...

I am using Resilience4J 0.17.0 version